# Copy and Pasting to a new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the code below to copy and paste the row to a new worksheet. When testing manually it seems to work but when running macro excel freezes. Basically if column L has the word Completed it shoud copy and paste that row to the Completed worksheet then return and delete the original row (everything with the work completed should be moved to completed folder)

```
Public Sub Completed()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheets("BPM-Other").Select
    FinalRow = Range("L11579").End(xlUp).Row
    For x = FinalRow To 2 Step -1
        ThisValue = Range("L" & x).Value
        If ThisValue = "Completed" Then
           Range("A" & x & ":O" & x).Cut
            Sheets("BPM_Other Completed").Select
            nextrow = Range("L10500").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Range("A" & nextrow).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Sheets("BPM-Other").Select
            Range("A" & x & ":L" & x).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
     Next x
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: The problem with this logic is that you are changing the number of rows inside of the loop  that is determined by the number of rows. You can't do that. You will get unpredictable results. Try not to think about it in terms of cut/paste and having certain things selected. It needs to be written in such a way that does not depend on `Select` and `Activate`/`ActiveSheet` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Answer (score 1):

I used, excel filter and copy, filter and delete option to accomplish the work. Please have a look at the below code.

Logic I used here is- Filter 12th column with value 'Completed'**->** Insert the filtered rows into target sheet, starting after last used row **->** Delete all the Completed rows in source sheet **->** Remove the filter in source sheet

```
Sub filter()
'specify sheet name
src = "BPM-Other"
tar = "BPM_Other Completed"

'calculating last used rows in both source and target sheet
src_last = Sheets(src).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
tar_last = Sheets(tar).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


With Sheets(src)
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    'assuming O is your last column, change as needed
    With .Range("A1:O" & src_last)
        'L is 12th column
        .AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="Completed"
        'Offset used to ignore the header
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Sheets(tar).Range("A" & tar_last + 1)
        'delete the rows
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
End With

'to remove the filter in source sheet
On Error Resume Next
    Sheets(src).ShowAllData
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```